Getting an exception as java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Rotatable. May i know how to resolve this error
I am trying to open the calculator application from my device through this script.
public class OpenCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {

        openCalculator();

    }

    public static void openCalculator() throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "ZD22224RKZ");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, 13); // without quotes
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "motorola edge_20");

        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.google.android.calculator");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity.Calculator");

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
        AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver = new AppiumDriver<WebElement>(url, cap);
        
        
    }
}

If I run this java class file then I am getting an exception as "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Rotatable"
and these are the versions i am using in pom.xml file
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>4.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>   
  <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
</dependency

I have tried with diff versions of appium client and selenium version but still I am not able to resolve this issue.
I just wanted to know which selenium version supports this rotatable class?

these are the dependencies and versions:   
org.seleniumhq.selenium
selenium-java
4.19.1


org.seleniumhq.selenium
selenium-remote-driver
4.0.0-alpha-6

don't put part of your question in a comment. You solve that by making sure that class is in the scope used

NoClassDefFound simply means that JVM could not load the class, perhaps because the class doesn't exist in the dependency version or it has been moved Refer , it is available in 3.9.1 but not in 4.19.1 https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/3.9.1/org/openqa/selenium/Rotatable.html
